# Redirecting STDERR & STDOUT to /dev/null in AIX fails

Tags: bash, redirect, aix

In AIX, I tried to redirect both STDERR & STDOUT to /dev/null but the redirection doesn't seems to be happening. What might be the problem?

```
bash-3.2#  /usr/sbin/lsgroup Test-Group | grep kbxb025 > /dev/null 2>&1
Group "Test-Group" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirections refer to commands, not whole pipelines. The outputs of `grep` go into `/dev/null`, but not those of `lsgroup`. To solve these issues, group the pipeline into a subshell:

```
( /usr/sbin/lsgroup Test-Group | grep kbxb025; ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply & it saved me lot of time.

Comment: @pprakash: You're welcome, and welcome to SO. It is customary to mark a correct answer to your question as correct (so that other poster's don't need to re-read it), and you do that by clicking the check-mark below the vote buttons on the left of the post.

Comment: Alternate syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file: `cmd &> /dev/null`. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html